# Problema com a função Insert_ID do AdoDB

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Em meu código realizo duas inserções utilizando a biblioteca Adodb 5, com o driver MySQL para PHP.

Porém em certos momentos ocorre de a função `Insert_ID()` retornar um id (chave primária) de um *insert* anterior ao realizado no momento, os dois *inserts* funcionam sem problemas, isso pode acontecer se o segundo *insert* retornar um *timeout*, e ele pode retornar um *timeout*?

Código de Exemplo

```
// Primeiro Insert
$db->Execute("INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES ('1')");

// Pega o primeiro id
$id_1 = $db->Insert_ID();

// Segundo Insert
$db->Execute("INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES ('1')")

// Pega o segundo id inserido
$id_2 = $db->Insert_ID(); /* Em certos momento pega o ID do primeiro Insert */
```

Answer (score 1):

E se você controlar os erros dessa forma:

```
include("adodb5/adodb-exceptions.inc.php");
include("adodb5/adodb.inc.php");

$db = NewADOConnection('mysql');
$db->Connect('localhost','root','senha','testdb');

$ok = $db->Execute("INSERT INTO table_1(nome) values('nome nome nome')");
if ($ok) // verifica se deu tudo OK!
{
    echo $db->Insert_ID();
} else {
    var_dump($db->ErrorMsg());
}

$ok = $db->Execute("INSERT INTO table_1(nome) values('nome nome nome')");
if ($ok) // verifica se deu tudo OK!
{
    echo $db->Insert_ID();
} else {
    var_dump($db->ErrorMsg());
}
```